# JS reduce loses first element of array

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a `reduce` function for reducing and formatting object keys and values to string in format `key1=value1\nkey2=value2`, but it is losing first element:

Sample data

```
{
  "key1": "value1",
  "key2": "value2"
}
```

```
private toMt5Set(data: any): string {
 const object = JSON.parse(data);
   return Object.keys(object || {})
          .reduce((acc, key) => acc + `${key}=${object[key]}\n`);
}
```

Comment: Please give sample input data.

Comment: `reduce((acc, key) => acc + `${key}=${object[key]}\n`,"")`; give initial value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding the initial value of acc

```
Object.keys(object || {}) .reduce((acc, key) => `${acc}${key}=${object[key]}\n`, '');
```

Output

```
key1=value1\nkey2=value2\n
```

Answer (score 4):

If I may, I'd like to recommend a small style improvement.

Your `reduce` function (with the '' initializer added):

```
.reduce((acc, key) => acc + `${key}=${object[key]}\n`, '');
```

is accessing `object`, which is defined outside the scope of `reduce`. These "outside of function" references are more difficult to reason about than "inside function" references.

You can avoid this "outside of function" issue by replacing your call to `Object.keys()` (which returns `key`) with `Object.entries()` (which returns `key, value`).

The "all within scope" version looks like this:

```js
Object.entries(object || {})
  .reduce((acc, [key, val]) => acc + `${key}=${val}\n`, '');
```

It's a small change, but it makes the code a bit easier to understand.